# How to save R list object to a database?

Tags: database, r, nosql

Suppose I have a list of R objects which are themselves lists. Each list has a defined structure: data, model which fits data and some attributes for identifying data. One example would be time series of certain economic indicators in particular countries. So my list object   has the following elements:

`data` - the historical time series for economic indicator

`country` - the name of the country, USA for example

`name` - the indicator name, GDP for example

`model` - ARIMA orders found out by `auto.arima` in suitable format, this again may be a list.

This is just an example. As I said suppose I have a number of such objects combined into a list. I would like to save it into some suitable format. The obvious solution is simply to use `save`, but this does not scale very well for large number of objects. For example if I only wanted to inspect a subset of objects, I would need to load all of the objects into memory.

If my data is a `data.frame`  I could save it to database. If I wanted to work with particular subset of data I would use SELECT and rely on database to deliver the required subset. SQLite served me well in this regard. Is it possible to replicate this for my described list object with some fancy database like MongoDB? Or should I simply think about how to convert my list to several related tables?

My motivation for this is to be able to easily generate various reports on the fitted models. I can write a bunch of functions which produce some report on a given object and then just use `lapply` on my list of objects. Ideally I would like to parallelise this process, but this is a another problem.

Answer (score 4):

I think I explained the basics of this somewhere once before---the gist of it is that

- R has complete serialization and deserialization support built in, so you can in fact take any existing R object and turn it into either a binary or textual serialization.  My digest package use that to turn the serialization into hash using different functions
- R has all the db connectivity you need.

Now, what a suitable format and db schema is ... will depend on your specifics. But there is (as usual) nothing in R stopping you :)

Comment: +1, Thanks for confirming what I suspected. I was hoping for some specific examples or at least some beware stories, but maybe my question is too general for that.

Comment: Well, it so happens that I was also thinking about something like this for fitted models at work---and could not think of an existing example somewhere.  Maybe we should just take it offline and try to work on quick little tutorial in a blog post or something?

Answer (score 1):

This question has been inactive for a long time. Since I had a similar concern recently, I want to add the pieces of information that I've found out. I recognise these three demands in the question:

- to have the data stored in a suitable structure
- scalability in terms of size and access time
- the possibility to efficiently read only subsets of the data

Beside the option to use a relational database, one can also use the `HDF5` file format which is designed to store a large amount of possible large objects. The choice depends on the type of data and the intended way to access it.

Relational databases should be favoured if:

- the atomic data items are small-sized
- the different data items possess the same structure
- there is no anticipation in which subsets the data will be read out
- convenient transfer of the data from one computer to another is not an issue or the computers where the data is needed have access to the database.

The HDF5 format should be preferred if:

- the atomic data items are themselves large objects (e.g. matrices)
- the data items are heterogenous, it is not possible to combine them into a table like representation
- most of the time the data is read out in groups which are known in advance
- moving the data from one computer to another should not require much effort

Furthermore, one can distinguish between `relational` and `hierarchial` relationships, where the latter is contained in the former. Within a HDF5 file, the information chunks can be arranged in a hierarchial way, e.g.:

```
/Germany/GDP/model/...
/Germany/GNP/data
/Austria/GNP/model/...
/Austria/GDP/data
```

The `rhdf5` package for handling HDF5 files is available on [Bioconductor](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.12/bioc/html/rhdf5.html). General information on the HDF5 format is available [here](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the same, but I had some good experience with time series objects with:

```
str()
```

Maybe you can look into that.